# Parameterization of Negative Binomial for Dynamical System Model Calibration/Fitting

Tags: distributions, inference, likelihood, nonlinear-dynamical-system

I'm studying about the applications of bayesian inference to fitting dynamical systems to observations.

So the model itself is a deterministic SIR model:

$$
f(R_0,D_{inf})=\begin{cases}
 \frac{dS}{t}&=-\beta S\frac{I}{N}
 \\
 \frac{dI}{t}&=\beta S\frac{I}{N}-\nu I
 \\
 \frac{dR}{t}&=\nu I
 \\
\end{cases}\tag{1}
$$
where $\beta=R_0/D_{inf}$, $\nu=1/D_{inf}$. The parameters we will calibrate/estimate will be $R_0$ and $D_{inf}$.

So the concept is finding the $R_0$ and $D_{inf}$ makes the model outputs, specifically the $I_t$ best fit the data, say $d_t$ and the uncertainty in the fit is captured by some probability distribution, i.e, Poisson:

$$d_t\sim Poisson(I_t)\tag{2}$$

meaning the actual observed time series $d_t$ follows some probability distribution around $I_t$.

---

**Problem**

In the case of $Poisson$ distribution, it is relatively easy to construct the likelihood for $R_0$ and $D_{inf}$ since all you have to do is to find $R_0$ and $D_{inf}$ that maximizes the likelihood generated from $(1)$ and $(2)$:

\begin{align*}
L(R_0,D_{inf}|d_1,d_2,\dots,d_n)
&=
\prod_{t=1}^nL(I_t|d_t)
\\
&=
\prod_{t=1}^n\frac{\exp(-I_t)I_t^{d_t}}{d_t!}
\end{align*}

then one could just use the following function for getting the likelihood

```
dpois(
   x = d_t,
   lambda = I_t
)
```

But how is this done for negative binomial? Generating likelihood we would have

\begin{align*}
L(R_0,D_{inf}|d_1,d_2,\dots,d_n)
&=\prod_{t=1}^n\frac{\Gamma (d_t+r_t)}{d_t!\Gamma (r_t)}p^{r_t}(1-p)^{d_t}
\end{align*}
where $I_t=\frac{r_t(1-p)}{p}$ would be the mean of the Negative binomial distribution.

how could I use `dnbinom()` for in this method of parameterization?

```
dnbinom(
 x=d_t,
 mu = I_t,
 size = ???
)
```

I'm slightly confused by the documentation and would like help on what should `size` be.

Please comment as well if this belongs to R Collective (StackOverflow) rather than CrossValidate rather than a straight downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Checking `?dnbinom`, the equivalent parameterisation is: your $d$ is R's `x`, your $p$ is R's `prob`, your $r$ is R's `size`, and your $I$ is R's `mu`.

`mu` is the mean, $I_t$ in your case. Then `prob = size/(size+mu)` (see docs). So

$$
\texttt{size} = r/(r + I_t)
$$

according to your parameterisation.

Comment: so $r$ would be constant throughout the likelihood?

Comment: I was lazy in my notation. What I meant was, where you see and $r_t$, that should be input into to `size` argument of `dnbinom`

Comment: But then $f(R_0,D_{inf})$ only gives us  $I_t$.  Does that mean $\left\{r_1,r_2,\dots,r_n\right\}$ would be another vector needed in the likelihood?

Comment: Tbh, I have no idea what deterministic SIR models etc. are. But I do know how to parameterise `dnbinom`. You might be able to have the $r_t$ as nuisance variables or something in the likelihood but I can't remember how to do that off the top of my head